# Warning using Scipy with Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm working with Python 2.7 to test the following example:

```
# importando pandas, numpy y matplotlib
import matplotlib as matplotlib
import scipy as scipy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# importando los datasets de sklearn
from sklearn import datasets

boston = datasets.load_boston()
boston_df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
boston_df['TARGET'] = boston.target
boston_df.head() # estructura de nuestro dataset.

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

rl = LinearRegression() # Creando el modelo.
rl.fit(boston.data, boston.target) # ajustando el modelo
list(zip(boston.feature_names, rl.coef_))

# haciendo las predicciones
predicciones = rl.predict(boston.data)
predicciones_df = pd.DataFrame(predicciones, columns=['Pred'])
predicciones_df.head() # predicciones de las primeras 5 lineas


np.mean(boston.target - predicciones)
```

But the response is:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py:1018:
>   RuntimeWarning: internal gelsd driver lwork query error, required
>   iwork dimension not returned. This is likely the result of LAPACK bug
>   0038, fixed in LAPACK 3.2.2 (released July 21, 2010). Falling back to
>   'gelss' driver.   warnings.warn(mesg, RuntimeWarning)

I used Brew and PIP to install Scipy.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is harmless and can be ignored.

The reason for the warning is just what it says: the default LAPACK which comes on macOS is a little old and SciPy works around a bug it has.

Comment: While this answer is more-or-less correct, it provokes a couple of obvious followup questions: are there *any* disadvantages to SciPy falling back to the 'gelss' driver (e.g. inferior performance, perhaps)? And is there a way to actually fix the problem described in the warning (instead of just silencing it as [suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50066647/1709587)) by upgrading LAPACK? If the answer to both questions is "yes" (and I don't know whether it is), then this answer probably isn't the optimal approach to take, and we ought to be upgrading LAPACK instead.

Comment: FWIW, since making my comment above I've tried pretty hard to get a newer version of LAPACK installed in a way that SciPy will actually detect and use during compilation, and failed. Future reader, unless you have some deep wisdom that I lack, I'd suggest you don't waste your effort and just ignore the warning (filtering it out if it bothers you). And if you *do* have some deep wisdom I'm lacking, then please enlighten us all!

Comment: Well, installing from a pypi wheel should be enough, I'd think.

Comment: Current SciPy will not use a newer LAPACK which should be already available. So the warning will be there unless SciPy switches to the current release of LAPACK, or LAPACK developers port back the bug fix to the old version. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5998

Comment: Newmost LAPACK certainly not, *newer* LAPACK, specifically, 3.4.0, yes.

Answer (score 6):

Try the code below to fix the issue:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", module="scipy", message="^internal gelsd")
```